# Hierarchy in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create a hierarchy in Report builder like this:

[image]

I have been looking into the documentations on online videos around that in SSRS and Report builder to do this. But I get just one element from per child hierarchy.

My SSRS/Report builder output looks like:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78123387/edit) your question to show your data and your current report design including any row groups. This should be really straight forward but without seeing more, it's hard to tell what you have done wrong.